What is the correct resistance on a "resistored" water heater element?
Edit: adding make and model: It's a Rheem Marathon MR85245 (85 gallon).
My water heater has two elements. Reading online, the top element is "resistored" or should be at least. From what I read this means it has a resistor integrated in it that prevents runaway and keeps the element from instantly failing if it is dry fired. Does this resistor change the resistance reading I should expect when testing it at the screws? The water in the heater is cold.
My top resistored element is reading about 450k ohms and the bottom non-resistored element is reading what I would normally expect at about 14 ohms. They are both 4500 watts with 240V supply. If I should expect the resistored one to read the same as a non resistored then it's obviously bad, but I can't find online what these resistored element should read resistance wise. TIA.

Make and model of the water heater will help.

Has been a long time since I studied electricity, but a resistor should add extra ohm reading to a simple circuit.  The maker of the water heater should have the numbers.

It's a Rheem Marathon MR85245 (85 gallon). And I've googled and read on Rheem's website etc. Can not find anything that states the resistored elements have different resistance than a standard non-resistored element. I do not know the make up of a resistored element, and really don't find much that tells if they are just like normal or not.

Someone on here might know about that model.

@MTA  This is probably close enough for an answer.  Fused and resistor difference makes a big change.

Not "resistored" but "fused". The Rheem product literature for that model says that the upper element is thermally fused to prevent damage from dry firing.

A thermal fuse does not change the resistance reading of the element at all until the fuse opens due to excessive temperature; then it reads infinite resistance -- though in the real world maybe 450Kohms is close enough to infinity to be the equivalent.
You should look for a thermal fuse associated with the upper element, since it's inexpensive and replaceable. If you don't know what to look for, you can take a photo and add it to your question.

I agree with the term thermally fused - however, on multiple websites, they call them "resistored" - Was just trying to use what appeared to be proper terminology. I agree 450k is pretty much an open circuit, but wasn't sure what to expect. I pulled it today and it was open. Replaced. Will be filling the tank shortly, after I go ahead and flush my geo-thermal water holding tank. thanks for the help. BTW the new "fused" one read about 14 ohms or so. So now I know. BTW, the thermal fuse is built into it, and these Marathon elements are expensive 5 to 7x what a regular cost.

And I suppose I should add. what a read on these thermal fused elements is they will self reset when cooled. It's meant to protect the element. on mine the element was open. it had holes in the tubes exposing the resister wire inside.

@driveguy I did come across a replacement thermal fuse for Rheem that looked like it plugged into a socket. Must have been for a different model. Glad you have the problem solved now.
